# Close a window in selemiun python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i'm trying to close a window in selenium, i have already tried:

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('link')
driver.quit()
```

Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best practice is to close the webdriver before quitting

```py
driver = webdriver.Firefox()

driver.get('https://stackoverflow.com')

driver.close()
driver.quit()
```

Comment: and the quit() function?

Comment: yes. driver.close() should close the window and driver.quit() should end your browser.